# How to properly estimate number of samples needed for multiple groups doing ANOVA test

Tags: r, anova

Suppose I performed an experiment for two groups, did ANOVA test and f for this experiment was 0.48 between these two groups, having n=18, power = 0.8 and significance (alpha) = 0.05

Now if I want to perform same experiment but within 4 groups of samples with same variance within groups, and then figure out which group have effect (perform Tukey Post Hoc test).

quesiton is - how to estimate size of groups needed.

I used power test to determine size of the groups:

```
pwr.anova.test(k=4,f=0.43,sig.level=0.05,power=0.8)

 Balanced one-way analysis of variance power calculation 

          k = 4
          n = 15.75307
          f = 0.43
  sig.level = 0.05
      power = 0.8
```

but since I am doing pairwise post-hoc analysis after between each group, probability of Type I error is increasing (since 0-hypothesis is there's no difference between all groups).

Therefore question is - how to correctly estimate n for 4 groups.

Comment: You could calculate the necessary sample size by using an external tool such as gpower (http://www.gpower.hhu.de).